# PowerShell New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy: How to show progress while copying databases?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell

Does anyone know about a possibility to show the progress of a copy database process on Azure? From my experience I can tell that databases that are scaled up (Premium) copy faster than Standard ones - but it is impossible to predict how long a job will take. I have copied a database within 20 minutes, but for the very same database, roughly same size, it took more than three hours another time. To optimize processes it would be quite helpful if I would know how long a particular job is going to take, or at least to have some kind of progress bar.

These are the parameters I am using:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName ... `
    -ServerName ... `
    -DatabaseName ... `
    -CopyResourceGroupName ... `
    -CopyServerName ... `
    -CopyDatabaseName ...
```

I know that you can see the progress if you start the copy operation through the Azure portal, but so far I was unable to find out how this works when automating things with PowerShell.

Is there any information about running copy jobs on the target/source SQL servers that can be queried?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a database state by querying the 'sys.databases' view on the master database of your target server.

The following SQL query returns the database name, with it's current state :

SELECT name, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '$($DbName)'

While the status is not 'online', the copy process is running.

Here is the view documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15